# Good articles/books to learn about tensors / tensor products?

Tags: soft-question, tensor-products, tensors, big-list

Currently a mathematics graduate student at a state university. I'm looking for articles or books (preferably free PDF links) that nicely explain tensors and tensor products at a graduate student level. I currently have a moderate background in linear algebra as well as a beginner's understanding of representation and character theory.

I'm interested in learning about tensors and tensor products and how they can relate to linear algebra and representation theory. Feel free to drop any suggestions/recommendations on pieces that you think explain tensors/tensor products well. Thanks!

Comment: Visual Differential Geometry Tristan Needham last section